# Internet connection error on one specific device (iPhone SE)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, reachability

I have iOS mobile app and there is internet availability check before getting data from server.

I use this code

```
func isInternetAvailable() -> Bool
{
    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
        }
    }

    var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
        return false
    }
    let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```

And everything is fine on hundreds of devices except one phone - iPhone SE.
When this iPhone is connected to internet over wi-fi - there are no problems but if this phone is connected over 3G or LTE - this function returns false and app is not loading data.

I updated iOS to last version, reinstalled my app many times. But I have no luck with this issue. The only thing I have in logs is

Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x17424b910 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://some_url.com/api/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://some_url.com/api/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.})

P.S.
As I know this is the only phone with this issue. App updates or iOS versions updates don't change anything for last year and the last thing that makes me mad - all other apps are working on this phone properly!

Comment: Is there parity between the iOS versions across all devices?

Comment: if not could be device version(s) vs specific device.

Comment: no - there are also a lot of iPhone SEs that don't have this issue. As I know this is the only phone with this issue. App updates or iOS versions updates don't change anything and the last thing that makes me mad - all other apps are working on this phone properly!

Comment: Can you verify you can go to browser and put in your URL Calls with responses? http://some_url.com/api/

Comment: yes - URL is fine and i can open it in safari